# Symfony 2.1: How to pass parameter to custom form field type

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I'm building a custom form field type extending from 'EntityType'. I always want to return a subset of elements based on option passed.

In my Type:

```php
$builder->add('Categories','choice_category', array('code'=> 'CAT1', 'multiple'=> true))   ;
```

I've declared choice_category as service. work ok!.

```php
  bt.form.type.category:
  class: My\MBundle\Form\Type\CategoryType
  tags:
      - { name: form.type, alias: choice_category }
```

In CategoryChoiceType.php

```php
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{

    $resolver->setDefaults(
        array(
            'class'=> 'CmComunBundle:Comun\Nomenclador',
            'code'          => null,                
        )
    );
}


public function getParent()
{
    return 'entity';
}
```

I'm thinking about use query_builder option, but I don't know how to pass code option to setDefaultOptions method, I don't access to $options array here.

```php
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
        $resolver->setDefaults(
        array(
            'class'=> 'CmComunBundle:Comun\Nomenclador',
            'code'          => null,
            'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) use ($options['code']) {
               return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->where('c.parent_code = :code')
                    ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
                    ->setParameter('code', $options['code']);;
            }
        )
    );
);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You almost got it right, but you need to make "query_builder" dependent on the other option "code" by using this special syntax:

```php
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Options;

$resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'query_builder' => function (Options $options) {
        // return default value of the "query_builder" option
        // you can access $options['code'] here
    },
));
```

So in your specific example:

```php
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'class' => 'CmComunBundle:Comun\Nomenclador',
        'code' => null,
        'query_builder' => function (Options $options) {
            return function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->where('c.parent_code = :code')
                    ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
                    ->setParameter('code', $options['code']);;
            };
        },
    ));
}
```

This is also documented in the [OptionsResolver README](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/OptionsResolver/README.md).

Comment: Thank you for your time Bernhard. Awesome work in form component!

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the `code` value to `__construct` via dependency injection and store it for later use inside the `setDefaultOptions` method.

```php
class CategoryType{
    ...
    private $code;
    ...
    public function __construct($code){
        $this->code = $code
    }
    ...
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver){
        $code = $this->code;
        $resolver->setDefaults(
        array(
            'class'=> 'CmComunBundle:Comun\Nomenclador',
            'code'          => null,
            'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) use ($code) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                ->where('c.parent_code = :code')
                                ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
                                ->setParameter('code', $code);
            })
        );
    );
}
```

and in your configuraion:

```php
bt.form.type.category:
    class: My\MBundle\Form\Type\CategoryType
    tags:
        arguments:
                - some_code_value
        - { name: form.type, alias: choice_category }
```

Now, I haven't tried this but it feels like it should work this way ;)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response!. You are right. it works, but i need pass a diferent "code" value in each form class. I need something "more dynamic" like pass the "code" as field option like "multiple" and "expanded"